# How to find the printer driver properties

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, drivers, shared-printers, powershell-v3.0

I have 15 print servers in our environment in different offices. Before upgrading of drivers i would like to display a report with the below information.

- 32 or 64 bit and Driver
- last installed or upgraded date.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is only possible, in a consistent way, with Microsoft supplied standard drivers.

You can query a whole lot about them via WMIC.
(Can't supply details I'm afraid. I'm visiting family for the holidays and there isn't any Windows system nearby to test/check commands.)

For 3rd party drivers this will sometimes work, but usually not. 3rd party drivers are notorious for doing things their own way and not filling in the standard management fields in the WMIC database.

If anybody has a better solution I would love to hear about it.
Would safe me a whole lot of effort in the future too.